# How to list available instances of SQL Servers using SMO in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, smo

Can anybody explain me what I wrong I am doing in the following piece of code:

```
DataTable dt=SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServer(true);
Server sr = new Server("Test");

foreach(DataBase db in sr.DataBases)
{
    Console.WriteLine(db["name"]);
}
```

It gives an exception in `sr.Databases` that can not be connected.

Comment: Could be that your firewall (or something else) blocks osql's broadcast which tries to find available instances?

Comment: Why are you enumerating the SQL Servers, and then still instantiating just the one "TEST" one??

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at the following links they may be helpful:

- [Enumerate SQL Server Instances in C#, Using ODBC](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SubmitSQLInfoEnumerator.aspx)
- [How to get a list of available SQL Servers using C# (MSDN)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/fda283ef-5a8b-424d-b549-074ccc19c8d7)
- [Populating a list of SQL Servers](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=45)

Alternatively you could change your code to this:

```
DataTable dt = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(false);
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dr["Name"]);
    }
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: The question says that he/she needs to find the instance names. But the code he/she gave is for finding the databases in a particular SQLServer instance.

Comment: The question (not the unrelated answer) brought me here, so IMHO this is the best answer, and I'll add this: if you are looking for SmoApplication, this worked best for me: GitHub's "Unofficial.Sql.Server.Management.Objects.

Comment: The above code gives me only network servers. what if i want both local and network servers.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have a SQL Server with the instance name *Test*? If not, that is your problem.

It looks like you are trying to enumerate all of the local SQL Server instances. If so, this code will work:

```
DataTable dt = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(true);

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dr["Name"]);
    Console.WriteLine("   " + dr["Server"]);
    Console.WriteLine("   " + dr["Instance"]);
    Console.WriteLine("   " + dr["Version"]);
    Console.WriteLine("   " + dr["IsLocal"]);
}
```

Comment: The above code gives me only network servers. what if i want both local and network servers.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case the question is titled wrong i.e. he wants to find the databases in the particular instance:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Server sr = new Server("MACHINE_NAME\\INSTANCE_NAME");

            try
            {
                foreach (Database db in sr.Databases)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(db.Name);
                }
                Console.Read();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Else Lucas Aardvark answer is most appropriate.

Comment: You don't need the call to SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers as the return value is not used.

Answer (score 1):

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

       RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server");
        String[] instances = (String[])rk.GetValue("InstalledInstances");
        if (instances.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (String element in instances)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(element);    // element is your server name                
            }
        }
```

Comment: this will only return 32bit servers if compiled as 32bit app and the same for 64bit

Comment: is it possible to get the installed instances without accessing registry ?