# Enumerate available SQL Servers from .Net

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, environment

Anyone know if there is a more "up to date" way of enumerating all available SQL Server instances via .Net, i.e. without using System.Data - DataTable/DataRow bits.

```
SqlDataSourceEnumerator sqlEnumerator = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
DataTable dt = sqlEnumerator.GetDataSources();
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row["ServerName"]);
    Console.WriteLine(row["InstanceName"]);
    Console.WriteLine("*******************************");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list available instances of SQL Servers using SMO in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130580/how-to-list-available-instances-of-sql-servers-using-smo-in-c)

Comment: @JohnFx I did see that but I'd like to avoid a dependency on SMO if possible

Answer (score 3):

You can find several answers [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130580/how-to-list-available-instances-of-sql-servers-using-smo-in-c)

Comment: Its interesting why somebody gave me -1?