# List all SQL instances, and their tables

Tags: c#, sql

I want to list all SQL server instances and their tables.

I have code that lists all the servers correctly but I cannot seem to get a list of their tables.

```
        DataTable dataSources = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();
        foreach (DataRow row in dataSources.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server Name:" + row["ServerName"]);

            foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" - Item: "+ item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list available instances of SQL Servers using SMO in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130580/how-to-list-available-instances-of-sql-servers-using-smo-in-c)

Comment: That shows how to get server names not table names, thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query what tables are in a db using `sys.Tables`.  See below:

```
USE YourDBName
GO
SELECT name FROM sys.Tables
GO
```

Comment: That would mean I have to be authenticated on that server to be able to see table names doesn't it?

Comment: authentication is a standard requirement for obtaining data!

Comment: Yes that is correct, if you want information about the database you will need to be authenticated.  This is a good thing.