# Find what sql versions(!) installed by folders?

Tags: sql-server

I've seen this link, but with no help:
[How can I determine installed SQL Server instances and their versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions)

So here is my question:
[image]

I want to see what versions of sql are installed on my computer.

If I'm running a query and typing :

```
select @@version
```

It tells me the running thread version. (which I don't want)

I want to see all of the versions - if installed!

Example: a computer can have sql 2000, 2005, 2008 ,2008R2

I've attached a print screen for my sql server folders.

I know that

```
80 = SQL Server 2000
90 = SQL Server 2005
100 = SQL Server 2008
```

How ever, it is not a rule.

Since 2008 creates both 80, 90.

It seems that the only way to find what versions are installed (besides regedit) is by the Sql Server Configuration manager.

[image]

Questions:

1) Is it possible by file system only, to detect what versions I have installed?

2) Is there any other way (besides registry), to see what SQL versions installed?

3) I read that mssql.1 is for the engine. What about MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS? Why it doesn't have mssql.4 number? MSDN says that it's a sequential ID of installed components.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **SQL Server 2008 Discovery Report**
>
> How can i tell what SQL Server features and version do I have
>   installed? This question has been asked a lot recently.  Starting in
>   SQL Server 2008, we added a SQL Server discovery report as an option
>   on the Tools page on the Installation Center.  When you click on the
>   link below, SQL Server will be started to discover the SQL Server
>   features.
>
> The SQL Server Discovery Report is saved to %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\
>
> Options:
>
> You can also generate the Discovery report through the command line.
>   Run “Setup.exe /Action=RunDiscovery” from a command prompt If you add
>   “/q” to the command line above no UI will be shown, but the report
>   will still be created in %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup
>   Bootstrap\Log\20091112_082147.

Reference:

- [SQL Server 2008 Discovery Report](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/petersad/archive/2009/11/13/sql-server-2008-discovery-report.aspx)

Comment: Why do it the hard way. When you can do it with an already implemented feature:)

Comment: @Arion, The real question is why did Microsoft not make it usably-obvious to find out the version in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

**Usually**,

- SQL Server 2005 uses the following directory naming scheme: `MSSQL.1, MSSQL.2, ...`,
- SQL Server 2008 uses `MSSQL10.<INSTANCENAME>`, and
- SQL Server 2008R2 uses `MSSQL10_50.<INSTANCENAME>`.

However, since the data directory can be changed during installation (at least for newer SQL Server versions), this is not a reliable way to detect SQL Server instances.

Comment: so the 80,90,100 folders related to what  ?

Comment: The MSSQL.* directories contain the instance data, the 80/90/... directories contain the executables and support files.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... If you want to know what versions do you have using only "the filesystem", the closest thing I know is opening the errorlog (~MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG) and whenever you start a connection, the sql server instance version is logged. You can search for "Microsoft SQL Server" and you will see things as "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1)" or Microsoft SQL Server 2003" and so on

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET, you can use the [SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms210334.aspx) method from SMO to enumerate all local SQL servers and get their version info.

Here is an [SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1130637/64161).