# How to get list of available SQL Servers using C# Code?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have created a desktop application. On application launch I want to display the list of all available SQL Server instances on the local PC, and allow to choose a SQL Server name to connect with.

Is there anyway to get the list of all SQL Server instance names that are available on the local PC?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list available instances of SQL Servers using SMO in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130580/how-to-list-available-instances-of-sql-servers-using-smo-in-c)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
string myServer = Environment.MachineName;

DataTable servers = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();
for (int i = 0; i < servers.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (myServer == servers.Rows[i]["ServerName"].ToString()) ///// used to get the servers in the local machine////
     {
         if ((servers.Rows[i]["InstanceName"] as string) != null)
            CmbServerName.Items.Add(servers.Rows[i]["ServerName"] + "\\" + servers.Rows[i]["InstanceName"]);
         else
            CmbServerName.Items.Add(servers.Rows[i]["ServerName"].ToString());
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr.Pranay . It works 100%, but must modify the code of  ** servers.Rows["ServerName"].ToString()** to ** servers.Rows[i]["ServerName"].ToString() **. However, that is what I want.

Comment: What is CmbServerName?

Comment: @InsideMan, most likely CmbServerName is a Winform ComboBox. Why is that important?

Comment: @GabrielMariusPopescu the combo box is not important at all

Answer (score 4):

```
        //// Retrieve the enumerator instance, and then retrieve the data sources.
        SqlDataSourceEnumerator instance = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
        DataTable dtDatabaseSources = instance.GetDataSources();

        //// Populate the data sources into DropDownList.            
        foreach (DataRow row in dtDatabaseSources.Rows)
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row["InstanceName"].ToString()))
                Model.DatabaseDataSourceNameList.Add(new ExportWizardChooseDestinationModel
                {
                    DatabaseDataSourceListItem = row["ServerName"].ToString()
                        + "\\" + row["InstanceName"].ToString()
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources()
```