# Listing available SQL Servers with instances does not include SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using the following code to list all available SQL Servers (it is [taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10781356/670017)):

```
DataTable servers = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();
for (int i = 0; i < servers.Rows.Count; i++)
{
     {
         if ((servers.Rows["InstanceName"] as string) != null)
            CmbServerName.Items.Add(servers.Rows["ServerName"] + "\\" + servers.Rows["InstanceName"]);
         else
            CmbServerName.Items.Add(servers.Rows["ServerName"]);
      }
  }
}
```

On my local system (computer name SERVER-1) I have SQL Server 2012 Express, and on remote SERVER-2 I had SQL Server 2008. So when I run this code, it returns this:

```
SERVER-1
SERVER-2\SQLSRVR2008INSTANCENAME
```

When it's supposed to be:

```
SERVER-1\SQLEXPRESS
SERVER-2\SQLSRVR2008INSTANCENAME
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the SQL Browser service running on SERVER-1?  Did you create an exception in the firewall to allow incoming connections for UDP port 1434?

Comment: I can connect and use either SQL server, so yes all ports are configured correctly. Now what do I need SQL Browser for in this case?

Comment: SQL Browser allows you to view the instances on the server.

Comment: See here for more information about the SQL Browser Service.  http://www.bobpusateri.com/archive/2010/09/a-look-at-the-sql-server-browser-service/

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the local Express instance on SERVER-1 is really named `SQLEXPRESS`? On that machine if you go to SQL Server Configuration Manager, what do you see under SQL Server Services? You will likely see `SQL Server (MSSQL)` (a default instance) and not `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)` (a named instance). You can install multiple instances of SQL Express, and either 0 or 1 can actually be a named instance called `SQLEXPRESS`. So just because it is SQL Express does not mean the instance name is automatically `SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: `SERVER-1\SQLEXPRESS` is how I connect to it in SSMS.

Comment: Just humor us and tell us what you see in Configuration Manager please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can locate local instances in registry.I had same issue long time back.The following link helped me
[SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources() does not locate local SQL server 2008 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824188/sqldatasourceenumerator-instance-getdatasources-does-not-locate-local-sql-serv)