# How do you check for existance of local instance of database from application code in a fast and safe way?

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqlconnection

What is the way to find out if,

- there is a locally running instance of SQL Server
- if so, does database X exist?
- if so, can databse X be connected to using integrated security?

I want to accomplish the above at application startup in the cleanest possible way.  Specficially, I'm worried about introducing the kind of delay I commonly see when I click on a dropdown to browse for databses in a connection wizard of various dev tools.

I can make the assumption of the instance name being either `.` or `.\sqlexpress`.

The end users are mostly running Windows XP.

The actual context of this is I want to automatically have my application sense a local database that developers can have installed.

If it's as simple as creating a a SqlConnection with the apprpriate values in the connection string, and that is what is safe and the recommended way, then I'm good with that.  I'm asking this because I'm trying to be safe about not introducing a bad end user experience.

Answer (score 1):

If you know to look at either `.` or `.\sqlexpress` simply attempt to connect in a `try-catch` and perform a select from `master.sysdatabases`.

If you don't know the server, then you can use [SQL Server Management Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) libraries to list all instances / databases that are discoverable.  This question details how:

[How to list available instances of SQL Servers using SMO in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130580/how-to-list-available-instances-of-sql-servers-using-smo-in-c)

The SMO `Server` class then has a [`Databases`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.databases) property to iterate.

Comment: i've always had this feeling that SMO was fairly heavyweight, but if it turns out to be nothing more than some assemblies I can deploy with my application, this might be a good solution, thanks!

Comment: @AaronAnodide It'll be slower because it enumerates all discoverable servers. If you know the servers, try to connect and manually query master.sysdatabases.

Answer (score 1):

Connect to `(local)` server.  If good, then switch to `master` database.  Then run this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM sysdatabases WHERE name = 'YOUR DB NAME HERE'
```

Comment: (local) will only find the default instance, not any named instances running locally (ie, `.\sqlexpress`).

Answer (score 0):

Use the property SqlConnection.ConnectionString and set the value for Connection Timeout. The default value is 15 seconds, which is a long time. So if you enumerate all the DB servers, as in Adam’s idea, and decrease the timeout value, then perhaps the user experience won’t be so bad.

More details are at [SqlConnection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) .

I don't want to make a SQL query because that may take a long time before it fails.

@Aaron, Let us know what you decide.