# How to retrieve all possible server names through C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, ado.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to list available instances of SQL Servers using SMO in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130580/how-to-list-available-instances-of-sql-servers-using-smo-in-c)

I'm writing a quick application which is to present the user with a list of server names/instances he or she may choose from to connect to an SQL Server database.  Basically I am trying to populate these options into a combobox, which should have options similar to these:

- (local)
- Joe-PC\SQLEXPRESS
- etc.

I have successfully obtained the databases corresponding to a server, and their respective tables, through ADO.NET.  However, I cannot find any code samples which allow me to retrieve the above data.

Comment: may be this would help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6t1z9x2.aspx ? but this is mainly the instances of a particular SQL Server

Comment: We used to do this using SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) API... try searching for examples using that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms212724.aspx) :
- Just add Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll assembly (You can find it in Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies SQL SERVER 2008) to your project resources.
- You can always refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.smoapplication.aspx).
- Here is the function you need :

```
SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers();
```

Comment: Don't forget to put this in in a background worker otherwise application will suck while looking for instances.

Comment: Why, is it a constant process? Does it not just execute once when called?

Comment: It actually takes a little bit of time to enumerate servers. you can show progress bar in indeterminate state while process is working.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use the SQL Browser Service. You can use the [`SqlDataSourceEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.aspx) to enumerate all SQL server instances that are have their SQL Browser service running.

The `GetDataSources` method will return a DataTable of available instances. The [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.getdatasources.aspx) provides a code example, too.

This is the same mechanism that SQL Server Management Studio will use to populate its server drop down on the connection dialog.

Answer (score -1):

The dirty way to do it, is to have a service that tries to connect to all the servers.  If the connection fails, you know the server is offline and not to publish that server as a viable option.